# Variable was never mutated...or Constant being used before initialized

Tags: ios, json, swift, api

So I'm wanting to get jsonMeals data back and use it outside of this function.
However it seems no matter where I place my json variable I get an error. Changing it to a let does as well although a different one. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Error:

```
Constant 'json' used before being initialized // Variable 'json' was never mutated; consider changing to 'let' constant
```

```
        func getApiDetailData(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
            var json: Any?
            let urlString = "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=\(id)"
            let url = URL(string: urlString)
            
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
                    do {
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!)
                        print("\(json)Testing")
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            completed()
                        }
                    }
                    catch {
                        print("Error getting detail JSON data:\(error)")
                    }
                guard let json = json as? [String : Any],
                      let jsonMeals = json["meals"] as? [String: Any] else {
                          print("No meals in json \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                        return
                    }
                print("testing jsonMeals\(jsonMeals)")
            }.resume()
        }
```

Comment: You should return the data via `completed`.

Comment: @meaning-matters How about the issue with my variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this example code:

```
func getApiDetailData(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
    //   var json: Any?   // <-- remove, never used
    let urlString = "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=\(id)"
    let url = URL(string: urlString)
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        do {
            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!)
            print("\(jsonData) Testing")
            
            guard let json = jsonData as? [String : Any],
                  let jsonMeals = json["meals"] as? [[String: Any]] else {
                print("No meals in json \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                completed()  // <-- here
                return
            }
            print("testing jsonMeals \(jsonMeals)")
            completed()  // <-- here
        }
        catch {
            print("Error getting detail JSON data:\(error)")
            completed()  // <-- here
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Or, if you want to return the `jsonMeals` results:

```
func getApiDetailData(completed: @escaping ([[String: Any]]?) -> ()) {  // <-- here
  //  var json: Any?   // <-- remove, never used
    let urlString = "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=\(id)"
    let url = URL(string: urlString)
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        do {
            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!)
            print("\(jsonData) Testing")
            
            guard let json = jsonData as? [String : Any],
                  let jsonMeals = json["meals"] as? [[String: Any]] else {
                print("No meals in json \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                completed(nil)  // <-- here
                return
            }
            print("testing jsonMeals \(jsonMeals)")
            completed(jsonMeals)  // <-- here
        }
        catch {
            print("Error getting detail JSON data:\(error)")
            completed(nil)  // <-- here
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I noticed I was declaring json twice. Once in the do and then outside of it. I need to read up some more on completed.

Comment: glad it helped. Minor update of my answer. Changed `let jsonMeals = json["meals"] as? [[String: Any]]` and associated return type. You may also want to look at my test code at: https://github.com/workingDog/FreeMeal